# View does not update when selection changes, after moving it to separate XIB file

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, xib, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

My OS X application has an `AppDelegate` with:
- a managed object context and
- an NSArrayController (from MainMenu.xib)

a `MainMenu.xib` with:
- an NSArrayController,
- a TableView to display all the objects and
- a bunch of TextFields to display the details of the selected object.

Everything is connected via Bindings and works perfectly well.

I want to add a separate window with a TextView for one of the details (notes).

As long as I add the separate window with the TextView to the MainMenu.xib and connect everything via Bindings, there is no problem, of course.

But I want to make a separate NSWindowController and XIB,
- `NotesPanelController` and
- `NotesPanel.xib`.

I added an NSArrayController property (arrayController) to the NotesPanelController and then initialized it with the arrayController from the AppDelegate. Now I bind my TextView in NotesPanel.xib to `File's Owner` with the following model key path: `self.arrayController.selection.notes`.

The TextView does no longer update, when the TableView (and by this the ArrayController) selection changes in the main window, though. What is wrong with my setup?

UPDATE:
I found out, the problem is not, that the selection is not observed, but changes to the text view in my notes panel don't get committed. Everything works as it should, when i enable continously update value in the NSTextView's value binding. But would this be an acceptable solution?

Comment: The bindings sound correct to me, but I'm worried that you call it a "Panel."   It may have its own event loop, and the bindings update may not get queued into it the way they're supposed to.

Comment: With *Panel* i mean an `NSPanel`, subclass of `NSWindow`. You think that makes a difference regarding the bindings? I can try a regular `NSWindow`.

Comment: @stevesliva No, there seems to be no difference between `NSPanel` and `NSWindow`. But I found out, the problem is not, that the selection is not observed, but changes don't get committed. Everything works as it should, when i enable `continously update value` in the `NSTextView`'s value binding. But would this be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Yup, that makes sense.  I mentioned the Panel only because when it runs modally it can screw up certain forms of immediacy.  Glad you figured it out.

Comment: @stevesliva Still the `continously update value` opition is not needed for a correctly working panel, if I place my panel in the MainMenu.xib. So there is something not quite right with the bindings in my setup with the separate nibs and controllers.

Comment: Reading [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/Concepts/BindingsOptions.html), it seem like either you want the option, or to resign first responder status.